# everwallet sendMessage: Parameter count mismatch

Tags: reactjs, wallet, everscale

Can somebody explain why i got this error ?
I use this plugin https://github.com/broxus/everscale-inpage-provider

[image]

when I use this script

```
 public async getEverWalletTransaction(
    recipient: string,
    price: any,
    payload: any,
  ): Promise<string> {
    console.log(this.wallet.address);
    console.log(recipient);
    console.log(price.toString());
    console.log(payload);
    const { transaction } = await this.ton.rawApi.sendMessage({
      sender: this.wallet.address,
      recipient,
      amount: price.toString(),
      bounce: true,
      payload,
    });

    return transaction.id.hash;
  }
```

Comment: For an answer, it is always good to make a minimally reproducible example, without it there is an assumption that your code interacts with a non-standard contract.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is from you recipient parameter.
here is the working code :

```js
// Import the library
import { ProviderRpcClient, Address } from "everscale-inpage-provider";

// Initialize new provider
const provider = new ProviderRpcClient();

// Send message like this 
  await provider.sendMessage({
    sender: new Address("<YOUR_ADDRESS_STRING>"), // e.g. 0:000...000
    recipient: new Address("<YOUR_ADDRESS_STRING>"),
    amount: "100000000", // 0.1 Ever
    // payload: "" as any,
    bounce: true,
    // stateInit: "",
  });
```

Please find below the transaction hash associated with the aforementioned script:

https://everscan.io/transactions/f9cc7b214fa74c29fda572fe394e5000981cc232bfdfcb790bb520b9a945e4fe